# WPF Listen to ListViewItem Removal

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, observablecollection, listviewitem

I want to "Listen" to the my main `ListView` and if one or more of the items are removed, their clones in the other `ListView`s will be removed aswell.

For example:
I have 5 items in the main `ListView`
In the second `ListView` I have 2 cloned items (their position in the main `ListView` are 0 and 2)
In the third `ListView` I have another 2 cloned items (their position in the main `ListView are 0 and 4)

When I remove item number 0 from the main `ListView`, I want it to be removed from all its clones from the other `ListView`s.

Right now, what I am doing, is when item removed from the main `ListView`, I loop through the other `ListView`s to check if it matches to the removed one, if it does I remove them aswell.

I read about the `ObservableCollection` but I cant understand how to implement it for my needs... would appreciate help / easy guide that will explain simply how to do it.

**EDIT:**
This one is WinForms solution - I dont know how to convert it to WPF solution plus I am not even sure if this is what I need
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4406/An-Observer-Pattern-and-an-Extended-ListView-Event

Comment: an `ObservableCollection` will notify you when the item is removed from the main `ListView` but it won't "take care" of the clones in your other `ListViews`, You'll still need to handle that yourself. since you already achieved this `what I am doing, is when item removed from the main ListView ...` I don't see how this can help you

Comment: How are you creating the `Clones` for the other `ListViews`? any particular reason with they can't be just a refernce to the same object?

Comment: You cant add same Item to two different ListViews..., the Items are Custom UserControl and the clone is function located inside the UserControl class:         public WindowItem Clone()
        {
            return new WindowItem(window);
        }

Comment: Dont ask me why is that, its impossible.. when u try to do that u get exception that the Item already has a logical parent...

Comment: Then something in you design is wrong ... How are you adding the UserControl to your ListView? are you using [DataBindings](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=DataBindings&oq=DataBindings&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l5.2003j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=122&q=DataBindings+WPF&safe=off)?

Comment: listView1.Items.Add(new WindowItem(parameters)), not using DataBindings. is it the right way in this case? it will solve my problem?

Comment: This is your problem. I suggest you learn about [MVVM](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/eladkatz/archive/2011/02/04/mvvm-102.aspx) and [DataBindings](http://webmaster.org.il/articles/wpf-data-binding). your [`ListView.ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) should be bind to a collection in your window's [DataContext](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/321899/DataContext-in-WPF). This way your `UserControl` can be in multiple collection's without the need to clone it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To illustrate my point from the comments section, Say you have a `UserControl` called `WindowItem` that implements a `Clone` method:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.WindowItem"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
      <Button Content="Click me"/>  
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I create a class that will hold mutiple collections of `WindowItem`

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {

    }

    public ObservableCollection<WindowItem> FirstCollection { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<WindowItem> SecondCollection { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<WindowItem> ThirdCollection { get; set; }
}
```

I also create a `View` contaning three `ListViews`, binded to my collections via [Data Bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FirstCollection}"/>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SecondCollection}"/>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ThirdCollection}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Next, in the constructor of my MainWindow (known as `View`), I set it's [DataContext](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/321899/DataContext-in-WPF) to be the class I created earlier (known as `ViewModel` in [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)).

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
}
```

Now, I can create cloning of my user controls for the different collection, shown in different lists in my view and register to the `CollectionChanged` event of the first collection. Here is an example of doing so from the ViewModel constructor

```
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        FirstCollection = new ObservableCollection<WindowItem>();
        SecondCollection = new ObservableCollection<WindowItem>();
        ThirdCollection = new ObservableCollection<WindowItem>();

        var windowItem = new WindowItem();
        FirstCollection.Add(windowItem);            
        SecondCollection.Add(windowItem.Clone());

        // Register to collection changes notifications
        FirstCollection.CollectionChanged += FirstCollectionChanged;
    }
```

`FirstCollectionChanged` will fire whenever the first collection changes. You can "listen" for a removal action, and then remove the matching items from you other collections.

```
     private void FirstCollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            // Remove matching item from second and third collection.
        }
    }
```

You can test it by removing an item from the first collection

```
FirstCollection.RemoveAt(0);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I read all the 3 references u gave in the comment of the main question and I understood the idea behind it. When I moved to your illustration above, I could follow almost everything until the part of the FirstCollection.Add(windowItem); and SecondCollection.Add(windowItem), how can you do that? I mean, there's no link between the main window to the ViewModel which is declared in the MainWindow function as DataContext - but it doesnt let me reach/touch them (I also tried it and as I expected I cant do  add item to the collection...)

Comment: @Ron The link between the main window and the ViewModel is this line `DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();` in the main window constructor. This is what lets you bind controls in your View to the collection properties in your ViewModel. Where are you trying to add the UserControl to the collections?

Comment: @Ron Im my implementation I did so from the ViewModel's constcutor , as you can take another look in my updated answer (btw, this isn't a best practice at all and was just for the simplicity of the explanation..)

Comment: 1. I tried to add the UserControl to the collections in the main window and not in the ViewModel - I fixed it. 2. I have 2 functions in the ViewModel, the constructor function which declare the 3 new collections and function public void AddItem(WindowItem wi){ FirstCollection.Add(wi); SecondCollection.Add(wi); } - it add the Item only to the first collection (YES, I Binded both collections to different listviews, when I change the order it only add to the SecondCollection.

Comment: @Ron YOU ARE RIGHT! I'm sorry I've mislead you. you CANNOT bind  the same referenced object as it draws it self only once. You will still need to use your clone method. I have updated my answer to accomplish what you wanted using an `ObservableCollection`. Sorry for the mistake again, but hey, atleast you got to learn some cool things about WPF :)

Comment: Why would I need all that code if in the end, to remove the match item I will need to find him using loop anyway?, I know when the list changes without the NotifyCollectionChanged (it changes when specific button clicked). I feel like all this code is unnessery

Comment: @Ron 1. Your question was on how to accomplish this using `ObservableCollection`, and this is how. 
2. The reason you need cloning and searching for matching items, is that you store visual items in those collection. If you were to store entities of your application you wouldn't have to do so.
3. This code is much more generic and loosley coupled as it uses MVVM architecture which is a best practice working with WPF

Comment: @Ron say you have a method called `SearchAndDelete` that gets a `WindowItem` and deletes it from collection 2 and 3. Say you implemented a call to that method when button `A` gets clicked. Now, You want to implement another button `B`. You'll have to make another call for `SearchAndDelete` again. infact, you'll have to call it whenever you'll need to apply that logic. with `ObservableCollection` on the other hand, you can listen to the removal operation AFTER it has already been done so you want have to explicitly make a call to your method. example of loose coupling...

Comment: Well after thinking deeply, I will stick to my solution instead of using the ObservableCollection because in the end, I will have UNKNOWN number of listviews and it's a bit harder to add ObservableCollections then listviews (I think so, since u declare the collections in the ViewModel) it will also be much easier for me to do it. But thank you very much for your explanations and time you invested.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding and removing items directly to/from ListView object bind it to some collection(preferably Observable Collection) and add/remove the items from ObservableCollection, it will be reflected on your UI also.

eg

```
ObservableCollection<WindowItem> MyCollection=new ObservableCollection<WindowItem>();
```

then add items by

```
MyCollection.Add(new WindowItem(parameters));
```

And for displaying your items from cloned listviews add an event handler to your main ObservableCollection like

```
MyCollection.CollectionChanged+=new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(CollectionChanged);
```

and

```
void CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //bind your another listviews to cloned items
}
```